# Is there a way to use toString and Split method in Nativescript Vue?

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript

I want convert date value from `datePicker` component into String to send `HTTP` request. But I can't use toString and split method like usual in javascript to convert it.

this is the code of `toString` method

```
dateChanged(args) {
  var dt = args.value.toString();
}
```

and this is the code of `split` method

```
dateChanged(args) {
  var arr = new Array();
  var dt = args.value;
  arr = dt.Split(" ");
}
```

I expect the date value can be converted into String so i can send `HTTP` request. when I insert date value into string variables, which contain url it always said undefined in date parameter.

Comment: Yes, you may convert the date object into string with JavaScript, the method name is `split` not `Split`. Why don't you simply use the methods in date object to get the date in which every format you like, for example `args.value.getDate() + '-' (args.value.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + args.value.getFullYear()`, could give you `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: thank you it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to format Date object to convert it to string:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat_ddMMMMMyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Date date=new Date();
String formattedDate=dateFormat_ddMMMMMyyyy.format(date);
```

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ";"  in ```SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());```

Comment: The above is Java code, not JavaScript. This may help you parse the date on backend.